# Join two queries on common property

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes written in C#:

```
class Animal
{
    string AnimalId { get; set; }
    string Species { get; set; }
    string CommonId { get; set; }
}

class Person
{
    string PersonId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Address { get; set; }
    string CommonId { get; set; }
}
```

I am querying these example classes as two separate queries. How can I join these two queries as one generic object based on the `CommonId`? Is there a way to return an object that has all fields from both classes as a new object without necessarily having to write out all of the properties from both classes?

***Edit***
Here's what I've done that works but I'm explicitly writing out each property.

```
var joined = animalQuery
                .Join(personQuery, e => e.CommonId, e.CommonId,
                (animal, person) => new
                {
                    animal.Species,
                    person.Name,
                    person.Address
                });
```

This works, but I'm wondering if it could be cleaner so that if I need to consider joining a new class with the same CommonId I don't have to write all out of the properties I want from that class as well.

Comment: What have you tried already? Post some code if you're having trouble getting LINQ to work the way you want.

Comment: look at the example on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-6.0 that has pet and person

Comment: One way would be the leave person and animal intact and reference them in the new object - something like `(animal, person) => new { animal, person }`. (I would need to double neck the syntax.) You could then reference `foo.animal.Species` and `foo.person.Name`.

Comment: Even it can be possible, we cannot create easily anonymous class dynamically and make compiler happy.

Comment: Svyatoslavl, yeah that's what I am starting to realize. Thank you all for the help

Comment: To elaborate, while it is possible to create an anonymous class at runtime and create objects for it, it isn't possible to have static typing work with it, which means you've stepped over a divide into leaving compiler type checking behind. You could also use a `Dictionary<string,object>` instead of a runtime anonymous class, but similar issues apply.